# Final steps in obtaining the $(m,n)$-labelled finite-dimensional irreps of the restricted Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, complex-numbers

I've been trying to understand how we get the $(m,n)$-labelled irreps of $SO^+(1,3)$ by reading posts such as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93517/), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293539/), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457304/) and links within, as well as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Finite-dimensional_representations) on the matter, and remain rather confused about how some of the final steps in the process work.

We want the irreps of $SO^+(1,3)$, so we look at the corresponding algebra, $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$. The six generators are labelled $J_a$ and $K_a$, $a \in \{1,2,3\}$, corresponding to rotations and boosts.

We then complexify the algebra, yielding $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)_\mathbb{C}$, and use a change of basis $A^\pm_a=(J_a \pm iK_a)/2.$ The new sets of generators $\{A^+_a\}$ and $\{A^-_a\}$ commute, and each generate an algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$, which is the complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. Thus we have the following isomorphism:

$$\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)_\mathbb{C} ~\cong~ \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$$

It is really the steps after this that I don't follow. We want the irreps of $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$, not its complexification. From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293539/) post, I see that the above result does **not** mean that $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$. So how do we actually get around this issue to finish with being able to label the irreps of $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$ using the labels for two irreps of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$?

Comment: Related answer on Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4184237/96384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any representation of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}$ trivially forms a [restricted representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation) wrt. to a Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
2. The interesting direction is the other way, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141354/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410952/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. We can study $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)_\mathbb{C}$ to get the irreps of $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$, so we use the labels of irreps of $(\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2))_\mathbb{C}$ to label the irreps of $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3)$, and the Lie subalgebra that we use is just the de-complexified one generated by $\{A^+_a\}$ and $\{A^-_a\}$?

Comment: Then, given the comments from SRS under this answer (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/293606/101126) to the post you linked, there is a one-to-one correspondence, via a "change of basis", between the representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$ used for classification, and the representations of the real restricted Lorentz algebra that we ultimately want.