# $SO(3,1)$ is locally $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, what does *locally* mean here?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, definition, lie-algebra, locality

I am learning Lie group and Lie algebra. I saw in a YouTube video "Supersymmetry lecture 02" from OpenCourseWare (OCW) at University of Cambridge at [11:17](https://youtu.be/xmvuC0J22gY?si=7QFz9p7aTpxYmIRt&t=677) that

> $SO(3,1)$ is locally $SU(2) \times SU(2)$.

What does *locally* mean here? Does it refer to the fact that the Lie algebra of $SO(3,1)$ is equivalent to two independent $SU(2)$?

I am new to the subject, and any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505

Comment: actually, *the complexification* of $SO(3,1)$ is locally $SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$.  As a real form, $SO(3,1)$ is non-compact so all its unirrep are infinite-dimensional, whereas there are finite dimensional unirreps of $SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$

Comment: Doesn’t “locally” here mean “in the neighborhood of any group element”? “Globally”, the entire group isn’t that direct product.

Comment: Also related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/682536/70245

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Two [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G,H$ are *locally isomorphic* iff their corresponding [Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}$ are [isomorphic](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=lie+algebra+isomorphism) $\mathfrak{g}\cong\mathfrak{h}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140666/11127) Math.SE post.
2. The YouTube video is strictly speaking wrong: The two Lie algebras $so(3,1;\mathbb{R})$ and $su(2)\oplus su(2)$ are *not* isomorphic. However, their [complexifications](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Complexification_of_a_Lie_algebra)$^1$ are isomorphic
   $$so(3,1;\mathbb{C})~\cong~sl(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{C}),$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ Notice how the lecturer around [13:30](https://youtu.be/xmvuC0J22gY?si=gC-7cSO6AdQn2HbM&t=810) introduces an explicit imaginary unit $i$ into the construction.